# How intelligent are Mini-Cons?

Tags: transformers, races

Question applies to the entirety of the Transformers universe. Where conflicts occur, the Aligned continuity is preferred.

Laserbeak, a mini-Con, has been described as a pet of Soundwave, a full-sized, regular Cybertronian (regular being the most common variant). Asking about Mini-Cons in general using Laserbeak as an example for context:

- How intelligent are Mini-Cons? For example, does Laserbeak possess the free will to choose to be Soundwave's pet or is it genuinely "domesticated"? Does it have the sentience to operate as an independent Decepticon or is its behaviour more "primitive/wild"?
- How much control do pet Mini-Cons have over their choice of forms? For example, whenever Soundwave scans a new form, is Laserbeak required to change form too to match the theme, or can it refuse?
- Adding to the previous question, when pet Mini-Cons like Laserbeak change form with their owners like Soundwave upon a new scan, does Soundwave's scan automatically reconfigure Laserbeak's form to match or does Laserbeak have to perform a separate scan on its own?

Comment: In the G1/BW/BM continuity, Ravage is reformatted with a new body and is indistinguishable from any other non-mini-con.

Comment: In the current "Transformers: Robots in Disguise" TV show, minicons have been shown to have free will, and even choose which "regular" Cybertronian they align themselves with, and they can (and have) change that alignment at will.

Answer (score 1):

A minicon's intelligence is entirely depends on the minicon themselves.

Transformers Armada has the best examples. 
During the episode 'Vow' Megatron ordered the minicons he has to fire at Optimus. Optimus refuses to harm the minicons despite all the damage they have afflicted on him. After that, the minicons fired at Megatron.

> In a much later episode, the minicons were created by Unicron and they all fought against him.

In the Aligned continuity, Micronus Prime is one of the Thirteen Primes and is the first minicon. While he did lack in size, he was one of the smarter Primes.

In Beast Wars with Ravage.

> His assignment was to retrieve Megatron and bring him back to Cybertron, but after Megatron showed Ravage the video of the old (G1) Megatron, Ravage shows he is more interested in the Decepticons rather than what he was supposed to do. His final words were "Decepticon, forever!"